# Accessing data from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am having difficulty getting data from JSON.

I am after doing a foreach() for json formatted data that I get from a API, but I cant get it to work.

Here is my code:

The $player_runes is the database variable, it works totally fine, my problem is getting the data of runeID for each Array (pages)

```
foreach($player_runes->pages as $statplayerrunesfor){

$statplayerrunesforune0 = $statplayerrunesfor->slots->runeId;

echo $statplayerrunesforune0;

}
```

Here is the JSON Data:

```
{
"29161162": {
"summonerId": 29161162,
"pages": [
  {
    "id": 24193964,
    "name": "nida",
    "current": false,
    "slots": [
      {
        "runeSlotId": 1,
        "runeId": 5273
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 2,
        "runeId": 5273
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 3,
        "runeId": 5273
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 4,
        "runeId": 5273
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 5,
        "runeId": 5273
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 6,
        "runeId": 5273
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 7,
        "runeId": 5273
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 8,
        "runeId": 5273
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 9,
        "runeId": 5273
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 10,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 11,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 12,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 13,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 14,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 15,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 16,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 17,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 18,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 19,
        "runeId": 5297
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 20,
        "runeId": 5297
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 21,
        "runeId": 5297
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 22,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 23,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 24,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 25,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 26,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 27,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 28,
        "runeId": 5357
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 29,
        "runeId": 5357
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 30,
        "runeId": 5357
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 24193965,
    "name": "adc",
    "current": false,
    "slots": [
      {
        "runeSlotId": 1,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 2,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 3,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 4,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 5,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 6,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 7,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 8,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 9,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 10,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 11,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 12,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 13,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 14,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 15,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 16,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 17,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 18,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 19,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 20,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 21,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 22,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 23,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 24,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 25,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 26,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 27,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 28,
        "runeId": 5337
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 29,
        "runeId": 5337
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 30,
        "runeId": 5337
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 60148113,
    "name": "zed",
    "current": false,
    "slots": [
      {
        "runeSlotId": 1,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 2,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 3,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 4,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 5,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 6,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 7,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 8,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 9,
        "runeId": 5245
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 10,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 11,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 12,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 13,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 14,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 15,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 16,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 17,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 18,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 19,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 20,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 21,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 22,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 23,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 24,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 25,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 26,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 27,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 28,
        "runeId": 5345
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 29,
        "runeId": 5345
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 30,
        "runeId": 5335
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 60148114,
    "name": "one",
    "current": true,
    "slots": [
      {
        "runeSlotId": 1,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 2,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 3,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 4,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 5,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 6,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 7,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 8,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 9,
        "runeId": 5253
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 10,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 11,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 12,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 13,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 14,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 15,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 16,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 17,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 18,
        "runeId": 5317
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 19,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 20,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 21,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 22,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 23,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 24,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 25,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 26,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 27,
        "runeId": 5289
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 28,
        "runeId": 5335
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 29,
        "runeId": 5335
      },
      {
        "runeSlotId": 30,
        "runeId": 5335
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
}
```

Comment: json_decode(); read about it

Comment: I already have it decoded, My question is how do I get access to the data runeId is it like how i done in the foreach ?

Comment: Check my answer, if you use `json_decode()` it becomes an array, not object.

Comment: `$statplayerrunesfor->slots` is an array. You need to use a `foreach()` loop over it to get all the `runeId`s.

Comment: The first player has 30 `runeId`s, which one did you expect `$statplayerrunesfor->slots->runeId` to return?

Comment: The first one. But the problem is due to this i think "29161162": {} at the start

Comment: I cant get this to work either $playerIDruneshgg = $player_runes->summonerId;

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you:

```
$player_runes = json_decode($variable_with_json, true);
foreach($player_runes['pages'] as $statplayerrunesfor){

$statplayerrunesforune0 = $statplayerrunesfor['slots']['runeId'];

echo $statplayerrunesforune0;

}
```

After decoding it become an `array` not an object.

Comment: Does not work, but i have already decoded it into a array the problem is the parts where i try to get the data like ->runeId. And some reason wont work makes page black.

Comment: Anyway it is always better to find out a solution on you own :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach(json_decode($player_runes->pages) as $statplayerrunesfor){

    $statplayerrunesforune0 = $statplayerrunesfor->{'slots'}->{'runeId'};

    echo $statplayerrunesforune0;

}
```

hope it works :)

Comment: Does not work, but i have already decoded it into a array the problem is the parts where i try to get the data like ->runeId. And some reason wont work makes page black.

Comment: @ForsakenHound Are you using the `true` option to `json_decode`? Then it becomes `$player_runes['pages']`.